# How to check non existence in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a model of a tower defined in prolog:
Each block has a position block(ID, POS). The level of a block is calculated in a different way.

```
rows(3).

block(a, 1).
block(b, 3).
```

In this case there would be space for 3 blocks (rows(3)) so there are the 3 different positions 1,2,3. How can I define a method which returns me 2 as the free position in this case?

Another example:

```
rows(4).

block(a, 2).
block(b, 3).
```

In this case the method should return 1 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prolog has some form of *negation* (but one must be careful when calling it negation), defined by: `\+`. You can search for rows that are not occupied by:

```
empty(X) :-
    rows(N),
    empty(1,N,X).

empty(I,_,I) :-
    \+ block(_,I).
empty(I,N,X) :-
    I < N,
    I1 is I+1,
    empty(I1,N,X).
```

The code defines two predicates: `empty/1` and `empty/3`. `empty/1` first checks the number of rows and calls `empty/3` with `empty(1,N,X)`: `X` is used to unify with an empty space and `N` is the number of rows.

`empty/3` uses some kind of *for-loop*, it iterates over `I`. For a given `I`, it checks if there is a `block(_,I)`, in other words: does there exists a block that is placed at space `I`, if so, that branch fails (and we use the next one). Otherwise, it is a fact that `X=I` is empty.

In the second case, we simply perform the *increment*: we first check if `I < N`, otherwise, we reached the end of the rows. If so, we increment `I` to `I1 is I+1` and then we call `empty(I1,N,X)` to check if the next row is empty.

If one calls this `empty/1` predicate for the second example, it returns:

```
?- empty(X).
X = 1 ;
X = 4 ;
false.
```

And for an instantiated query:

```
?- empty(1).
true ;
false.

?- empty(4).
true .

?- empty(3).
false.
```

Although for queries with known index, this predicate is not really efficient. For these you can build a query:

```
isEmpty(I) :-
    \+ block(_,I).
```

This will however **only work** if `I` is bounded (not a variable).

Comment: Why does the second function (empty(I,N,I)) need 3 parameters?

Comment: One for the current `I`, one for the bound `N`, and one to unify with results `X`: the empty spaces.